# why java is returning positive infinity when it exceed Double.Max_Value?

Tags: java, double

When i try to execute this code how result goes greater than Double.MAX_Value?Will overflow/underflow affect double data type in java?

Code:

```
   result = Double.MAX_VALUE * Double.MAX_VALUE;

   if (result > Double.MAX_VALUE) {
      // Some return statements.
   }
```

Comment: How have you defined your result variable ? is it Double or double ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.1)

> The result of a floating-point multiplication is determined by the rules of IEEE 754 arithmetic:
>
> - [...]
> - If the magnitude of the product is too large to represent, we say the operation **overflows**; **the result is then an infinity of appropriate sign**.

Since `Double.MAX_VALUE * Double.MAX_VALUE` is too large to represent, its value becomes infinity.

Comment: This is actually taken from the IEEE 754 standard for floating point arithmetic. Many computer languages follow this standard, so the behaviour is not necessarily Java specific.